# Maven3 global dependency exclusion

Tags: java, dependencies, maven

It is possible using Maven3 to have a global dependency exclusion instead of per-dependency exclusion ? If yes, how ? The documentation doesn't seems to be really friendly.

Thanks.

Later edit: Yeah, it seems that they'll fix this in 3.1 version of maven. So, till then, I guess I need to stick to the verbose way to do it for each dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It looks like](http://web.archive.org/web/20150525231329/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Global+exclusion+of+artifacts) this is not possible. There are a few open issues ([MNG-3196](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3196), [MNG-1977](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1977), [MNG-2163](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2163)) related to this

Comment: It seems MNG-19772 is fixed in 3.2.